# What happens if you try to detonate an expired nuclear weapon?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Ukraine had inherited a huge stockpile of nuclear weapons from the USSR. From what I understand, these nukes can expire as the isotopes inside start to decay. I was wondering what would happen if they had held onto these weapons, some of which might have expired today.

Will they simply fail to detonate or will they still explode but with a lesser impact? Presumably, all those weapons would have started with a much larger critical mass than the Hiroshima bomb.

Comment: If they held on to them, Russia would not have invaded. But it's not the actual payload that would have completely decayed, but the triggering mechanism. If it's Tritium, and provided the nukes were never maintained, they may already be useless. If it's plutonium, they can last up to a century, or more. It's hard to answer this with accuracy without specifics. You should post this on engineering.SE. It will make for a good question. Cheers.

Comment: You can read about the basic design of thermonuclear weapons at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermonuclear_weapon The Hiroshima bomb was a fission device, not an H-bomb. Tritium has a short half-life of 12.32 years, but the fissile isotopes have much longer half-lives, 24,110 years for Pu-239, and 703,800,000 for U-225.

Comment: The care and feeding of nuclear weapons depends strongly on the specific design. The exact design of the nuclear weapons that used to be in Ukraine is not *officially* public knowledge. Less so is the current condition of these devices.

Comment: A search term for US research into this question is "stockpile stewardship."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fission weapons will be good to go from a fissionability standpoint, but (perhaps) not from a corrosion standpoint. Fission fuel is very chemically active, and over long time it's possible the plutonium and uranium will oxidize and not properly implode.

From a fusion or a boosted fission standpoint, both processes rely on tritium which has a finite half-life and hence the tritium capsules in a fusion bomb must be regularly replaced. There are very few tritium sources available, and if you don't have one readily at hand, then your fusion bombs will fail.

That said, the fission primary in a fusion bomb will still do a lot of damage, and even a "fizzle" of a fission bomb will spread the fission fuel far and wide- as a so-called "dirty bomb".

Comment: Sigh. If only these people would stop using my beloved nukes for bad things. Canada has tritium we had to remove from CANDU reactors, and we can't sell it because of non-proliferation. Anyway. It seems like at least Russia and the USA have the ability to make more.  https://www.armscontrol.org/act/2002-10/features/breakdown-breakout-us-russian-warhead-production-capabilities